# What are the minimum permissions for a libpam-ldap unix domain socket?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, socket, pam-ldap

I'm setting up an LDAP server and `libpam-ldap` to run on the same host, communicating via a UNIX domain socket. I'd like to give this socket the minimum permissions necessary, so random local users can't try binding to LDAP and guessing other users' passwords. However, I can't figure out what user PAM is running as during authentication.

I've tried giving ownership of the socket and containing directory to every user on the system, to no avail. The only thing that seems to work is setting `a+rwx` on them, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: you're forgetting about ownership and group, so depending on that you can fine tweak as `a+` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @alexus: I'm not forgetting about ownership & group. If I set the directory to `drwxrwx---` I can't get it to work no matter what I set the user/group to. Setting `a+rwx` was to demonstrate that it's a permissions problem, rather than (for example) a typo in the pam-ldap config.